# Why is the purchase of US I bond only possible for US citizens/residents and US civilian employees?

Tags: united-states, bonds, government-bonds

I read on https://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/research/indepth/ibonds/res_ibonds_ibuy.htm:

> Who may own an I bond?
>
> Individuals: Yes, if you have a Social Security Number and meet any one of these three conditions:
>
> 1. United States citizen, whether you live in the U.S. or abroad
> 2. United States resident
> 3. Civilian employee of the United States, no matter where you live

Why is the purchase of US I bond only possible for US citizens/residents and US civilian employees?

Answer (score 0):

I can explain the regulations that lead to this:

[31 USC 3105](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/31/3105) gives the Secretary of Treasury the full authority to decide on the terms and conditions of the bond offerings. [31 CFR 359](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/31/part-359) and [31 CFR 360](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/31/part-360) are the relevant regulations issued by that authority.

The [31 CFR 360.5](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/31/360.5) discusses the general requirements for registration, one of which is the TIN:

> (1) Registrations requested must be clear, accurate and complete, conform substantially with one of the forms set forth in this subpart, and include the **taxpayer identifying number of the owner** or first-named coowner.

Taxpayer identification is either SSN or EIN issued by the IRS (See [31 CFR 359.3](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/31/359.3)).

> *Taxpayer identification number (TIN)* means the identifying number required on tax returns and other documents submitted to the Internal Revenue Service; that is, an individual's social security account number (SSN) or an employer identification number (EIN).

Note that it *does not* include ITIN. In order to be eligible for SSN, an individual must be either US Citizen, or US resident (with additional requirements) - see [20 CFR 422.104](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/20/422.104).

Civilian employees of the US Government are either citizens or green card holders, and would be considered residents wherever they live. Foreigners who are civilian employees of the US Government are allowed to purchase I Bonds only if they have an SSN.

Hence the requirements on TreasuryDirect.

There's also the regulations governing TreasuryDirect itself, specifically [this](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/31/363.11):

> **§ 363.11 Who is eligible to open a TreasuryDirect ® account?**
>
> Only an individual or an entity is eligible to open a TreasuryDirect account. In order to open a TreasuryDirect account, an individual or entity account manager must have a valid social security number (SSN), be 18 years of age or over, and be legally competent. An entity must have a valid SSN or employer identification number. The account owner must have a United States address of record and have an account at a United States depository financial institution that will accept debits and credits using the Automated Clearing House method of payment.

---

Why ITIN is not included in the list of valid TIN types? [31 USC 3102](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/31/3102) may provide an insight:

> The Secretary shall offer the bonds authorized under this section first as a popular loan under regulations of the Secretary that *allow the people of the United States* as nearly as possible an equal opportunity to participate in subscribing to the offered bonds